# WebStorm Node.Js Interpreter Issue

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am trying to use the WebStorm IDE for a node.js project. I have read the documentation and I think I have set everything up correctly. However, the IDE is giving me errors that aren't supposed to be errors. The program still perfectly fine event thought the IDE tells me there are errors:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, those are fake errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right JavaScript language version chosen? (Help...Find Action... "Javascript Language Version" will get you there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it runs fine but you are seeing alleged errors in the editor, you probably don't have the correct JS version set for the project. You can get there via Help...Find Action and the following images...

[image]

[image]